# Make background image always full height css?

Tags: css

I have a small landing page where I want the logo and subtitle along with a download link to be set over a photo. Like so:

```
<div id="photoHeader">
    <div id="logo">
        Logo Goes Here
    </div>
    <div id="sub">
        Make Awesome Mixes at Home, Fast!
    </div>
    <div id="downloadLink">
        <a href="#download">
            Download Now
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the background image to fill the width of the browser window and set its height automatically so it always maintains aspect ratio. I'm also going to set the logo, subtitle and link to size percentages so they shrink with it, but right now I can't get the background to maintain aspect ratio. This is the css I've tried:

```
#photoHeader{
background: url(http://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Mixer.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%
}
```

With this CSS, the background maintains aspect ratio but is cut off by the top of the browser. What am I missing here?

Comment: By _cut off by the top_, are you maybe referring to the default margins on a page? Try a reset like `* { margin: 0; }`

Answer (score 1):

May be you want to do this (add it to your css):

```
body {   
     background: url(http://www.examplesite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Mixer.jpg); 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```